# invoke-azvmruncommad is running from long time

Tags: github-actions, azure-powershell

I'm using Invoke-AzVMRunCommand in GitHub actions to run some PowerShell and bash scripts on multiple servers.

But Invoke-AzVMRunCommand is running for more than 30mins on some servers, it's a server problem or anything but Invoke-AzVMRunCommand is not finishing. The pipeline also running for a long time and not finishing. I have so many servers in the order, for one server it takes 30 to 50 mins, what about the remaining servers?

I want to stop or exit or skip the Invoke-AzVMRunCommand after running more than 30mins.

I need if conditions also:
If Invoke-AzVMRunCommand is finished on time, save the server details in one CSV file.
If not finished in time, stop the Invoke-AzVMRunCommand and save the server details in another CSV file.